# VS Code: Error while applying breakpoint, "Breakpoint ignored because target path not found"

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code

I am using chrome debugger extension in Visual Studio code to debug my backbone application. The launch.json file is like this;

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "https://localhost:3000/authenticate/app/110020",
            "webRoot": "D:/Apps/app",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "trace": "verbose"
        }
    ]
}
```

When i am trying to put a breakpoint in the app.js file which is present in "D:/Apps/app" directory, the following error is displayed,
"Breakpoint ignored because target path not found". The file app.js is not minified or combined.

Answer (score 0):

The answer for the original question was found here by the looks of things: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-chrome-debug/issues/462

In summary the issue was related to the poster requesting JS files with a querystring with no key eg

`https://localhost:3000/dd/2000/app/js/pp?112/src/js/build.js`

This caused an error is VS code. As of now the issue is still open.

Comment: Have provided a summary. Have also opened a new question related to this but with a different root cause https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49115446/how-do-i-set-up-vs-code-to-debug-js-running-under-asp-net-mvc