# How do I set up VS Code to debug JS running under asp.net MVC

Tags: google-chrome, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm using the `System.Web.Optimization` default bundler - running with optimizations disabled locally, and trying to get VS Code debugger hooked into chrome.

VS Code is talking to chrome OK (I can see console output in VS code), but I'm getting `breakpoint ignored because target path not found` when trying to add a breakpoint

```
    {
        "type": "chrome",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
        "url": "http://localhost:54330",
        "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
```

Here's a sample line from trace output which reads like the files are being found ok

```
From target: {"method":"Debugger.scriptParsed","params":{"scriptId":"182","url":"http://localhost:54330/Scripts/angular/app/components/Product/productIndexController.js","startLine":0,"startColumn":0,"endLine":41,"endColumn":4,"executionContextId":2,"hash":"F699CE42A4E66A41179BFB42F8FB23B6ABB6F607","executionContextAuxData":{"isDefault":true,"frameId":"(F6D07DAAA333F34A41904700967EB515)"},"isLiveEdit":false,"sourceMapURL":"","hasSourceURL":false,"isModule":false,"length":1244}}

Paths.scriptParsed: resolved http://localhost:54330/Scripts/angular/app/components/Product/productIndexController.js to d:\redacted\Scripts\angular\app\components\Product\productIndexController.js. webRoot: d:\redacted

To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"loadedSource","body":{"reason":"new","source":{"name":"productIndexController.js","path":"http://localhost:54330/Scripts/angular/app/components/Product/productIndexController.js","sourceReference":1158}}}
```

The log when setting a breakpoint:

```
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"event","event":"output","body":{"category":"telemetry","output":"setBreakpointsRequest","data":{"fileExt":".js"}}}
To client: {"seq":0,"type":"response","request_seq":10,"command":"setBreakpoints","success":true,"body":{"breakpoints":[{"verified":false,"line":7,"message":"Breakpoint ignored because target path not found","id":1002}]}}
```

Sample of output from `.scripts`

```
› http://localhost:54330/scripts/angular/lib/responsive-bootstrap-toolkit.js (d:\redacted\scripts\angular\lib\responsive-bootstrap-toolkit.js)
› http://localhost:54330/scripts/angular/lib/showdown.js (d:\redacted\scripts\angular\lib\showdown.js)
› http://localhost:54330/scripts/angular/polyfills/blob.js (d:\redacted\scripts\angular\polyfills\blob.js)
```

Comment: Also post the output of the `.scripts` command in the debug console

Comment: @RobLourens have added an excerpt